# CKQuery slow with CKAssets

Tags: ios, performance, icloud, cloudkit, ckasset

When I fetch for records with fields that are Strings (or others) it takes under 1 second:

```
 let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Messages", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE"))
    NSLog("Started fetching")
    self.publicDb.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (records, error) in
        NSLog("Finished fetching")
        print(records!.count)
    }
```

But, when this record type contains a CKAsset, the time for the query goes up to at least 3 seconds. This is not acceptable when I want to load an image that is 100kb. It's the same when I put the asset in as a reference and load it from there. What can I do to speed up queries for records that contain assets or is there any other way to store assets in a more efficient way?

Comment: 1) Assets are large compared to plain text fields. They will take a lot longer. Nothing you can do except make them smaller. 2) Use a `CKQueryOperation` instead of `performQuery`. It's faster and has a lot more flexibility.

Comment: You could/can store assets somewhere else? Using an API from a different source such as dropbox. I read too that in production things are faster, but best to bank on it. Other solutions,  use your own http server as a backing store or indeed use links and don't down load it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use an operation and set the quality of service:

```
CKQueryOperation *queryOperation = [[CKQueryOperation alloc] initWithQuery:query];

queryOperation.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfServiceUserInitiated;
```

If you don't set qualityOfService, you will get the background level and it will be slow.

Comment: This is a good answer. The fastest (but most costly) `qualityOfService` is `NSQualityOfServiceUserInteractive`.